# Delay state change with async/await?

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a custom error window that pops up in various situations. What I'm struggling with is getting the window to dissapear after 2 seconds.. Just a simple setTimeout to change the popup state to `active:false` is a bit unreliable because of the way the even loop works (i think?).

So I'm attempting an async/await way of doing it making sure it's always exactly 2 seconds. However the way I have done it below the timing still seems to be very weird, sometimes instant, sometimes 2 seconds.

How do I get my `removeErrorMsg` function to wait 2 seconds before setting the state?

```
///// App.js.js ////

const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    errorPopup: {
      active: false,
      message: ''
    }
  }

  removeErrorMsg = async() => {
    await delay(2000);
    this.setState({errorPopup: {active: false, message: ''}});
  }
}



///// ErrorPopup.js ////

import React from 'react'

const ErrorPopup = ({ message, active, removeErrorMsg}) => {


  if(active){
    removeErrorMsg()
    return (
      <div className="error-popup">
        <p>{message}</p>
      </div>
    )
  } else return <div></div>
}

export default ErrorPopup
```

Comment: setTimeout only guarantees minimum time to execute, it may be longer than the delay specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call the `removeErrorMsg` inside the `ErrorPopup` component within a `useEffect` function. Directly calling it will result in another delay being created which resets the state as soon as any other action in parent component tries to trigger a re-render leading to unexpected behaviours

```
const ErrorPopup = ({ message, active, removeErrorMsg}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
      if(active) {
         removeErrorMsg()
      }
   }, [active])


  if(active){
    return (
      <div className="error-popup">
        <p>{message}</p>
      </div>
    )
  } else return <div></div>
}
```

**P.S.** Although there is no gurantee that the setTimeout will execute immediately at 2sec, more or less it roughly execute around 2sec.

Comment: thanks for you help! this worked.. is there a neater way to do what i was trying to achieve?

Comment: I think what you have done above is a decent enough way